# lvs command cannot find LVM partitions, what tool to use to interact with these partitions?

Tags: lvm, arch-linux

When doing a `fdisk -l` there are two "Linux LVM" partition, but using `lvs` returns nothing and `lvmdiskscan` returns "0 LVM physical volumes".

What tool should I use to interact with these partition ? (Shrink, resize etc)

`sudo fdisk -l` gives

```
Disk /dev/sda: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: CED3CBCF-A524-4E54-8A0D-0341958E40C2

Device         Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048       4095      2048     1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2       4096    1052671   1048576   512M Linux LVM
/dev/sda3    1052672  868701837 867649166 413.7G Linux LVM
/dev/sda4  868702208 1000215182 131512975  62.7G Linux swap


Disk /dev/sdc: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdb: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

`lvmdiskscan`gives

```
  /dev/sda2 [     512.00 MiB]
  /dev/sda3 [     413.73 GiB]
  /dev/sda4 [      62.71 GiB]
  /dev/sdb  [     476.94 GiB]
  /dev/sdc  [     476.94 GiB]
  2 disks
  3 partitions
  0 LVM physical volume whole disks
  0 LVM physical volumes
```

`df`gives

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
dev              32G     0   32G   0% /dev
run              32G  628K   32G   1% /run
/dev/sda3        79G  1.2G   74G   2% /
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /tmp
/dev/sda2       488M   28M  425M   7% /boot
tmpfs           6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/1000
```

`pvscan` returns

```
No matching physical volumes found
```

`vgscan` returns

```
Reading volume groups from cache.
```

`vgs` and `pvs` returns nothing

When doing `fdisk -l` from an Ubuntu 14.04 live CD, the partitions are reported as `Linux` and not `Linux LVM`, with an ID of 83 instead of 8e, may it be that the tools installed on the arch installation wrongly detect the partitions as LVM, and LVM tools knows they are not LVM partitions and ignore them ?

Comment: Please add the output of `pvs` and `vgs` to the body of the question as well.

Comment: Please run the commands `pvscan` and `vgscan` and then paste the output of `pvs` and `vgs` as suggested above.

Comment: Seems like fdisk is wrong, that's all :|

Comment: Nope, fdisk is not wrong. But fdisk displays only partition type which is set to "linux lvm" (0x8e) for them, that's all. Were there ever any physical volumes created there?